# Insert query using jdbctemplate gives exception UncategorizedSQLException

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I'm using jdbctemplate for insert query. This query works fine in SQL server studio. But when I use using jdbctemplate, this gives the exception of UncategorizedSQLException

Total exception

```
 org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [INSERT INTO Test (ID, NAME) VALUES (?, ?)]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; The conversion from UNKNOWN to UNKNOWN is unsupported.; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The conversion from UNKNOWN to UNKNOWN is unsupported.
```

**My code is**

```
sqlServerJdbcTemplate.update(
        "INSERT INTO Test (ID, NAME) VALUES (?, ?)",
        new Object[]{101, "Dave"},
        new Object[]{Types.INTEGER, Types.VARCHAR}
);
```

There are only two columns ID and NAME of Integer and varchar type.

What is the issue in this flow? Any ideas would be appreciated.

P.S : SQL server is the DB

Comment: which DBMS you are using?

Comment: try without `new Object[]{Types.INTEGER, Types.VARCHAR}`

Comment: @YCF_L Its SQL Server

Comment: @YCF_L, it works after removing new Object[]{Types.INTEGER, Types.VARCHAR}. Please put that in answer. Will accept

Comment: The answer by @YCF_L is correct. You were using the wrong method

Comment: Check the Method args here https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#update-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-int:A-

Comment: yes @SangamBelose the OP can use maybe `new int[]{Types.INTEGER, Types.VARCHAR}` instead of `new Object[]{Types.INTEGER, Types.VARCHAR}`

Comment: Yes. He can use either..

Comment: @SangamBelose, Thanks for your answer as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid this problem you can remove `new Object[]{Types.INTEGER, Types.VARCHAR}` and make the DBMS detect the Type of each input :

```
sqlServerJdbcTemplate.update(
        "INSERT INTO Test (ID, NAME) VALUES (?, ?)",
        new Object[]{101, "Dave"}
);
```